# How to use export to excel in angular but for specific HTML tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a requirement where I need to use export to excel functionality in `angularjs`. For this I am using `saveAs(blob, "FileName"+ ".xls");` which is working fine.

I need to export the data excluding some tags, like images or any control (e.g. button or text area), basically I need only text content.

```
       scope.exportData = function (item) {
                      if (document.getElementById(item) != null) {
                          var tableContent = document.getElementById(item).querySelector('table').outerHTML;
                          var blob = new Blob([tableContent], {
                              type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedo***ent.spreadsheetml.sheet;ch***t=utf-8"
                          });
                          saveAs(blob, item + ".xls");
                      }
                      else
                          alert("No data to export");
                  };
```

Comment: To help you, please update the question with info about libraries you are using for the XLS generation and how the `blob` is generated.

Comment: Hi, updated the question